# Регистрация в сети AdMob

Tags: android

Вопрос к людям имеющим опыт работы с admob сетью. 
При регистрации необходимо указать «Business Name», я так понимаю это название ИП или ООО. что туда можно вписать если регистрируюсь как физ. лицо и ИП пока не планирую открывать и какие проблемы могут появится в будущем из за этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишите что угодно, на вывод денег это не повлияет.